# Есть ли в Python оператор строгого сравнения наподобие ===?

Tags: python, python-3.x, операторы

Просто обычное сравнение через `==` работает не так, как нужно:

```
>>> 0 == False
True
```

Comment: Нет, но python и так довольно строго по сравнению с js относится к типизации. Неявные приведения, подобные тому, которое вы указали, сделаны для удобства и являются скорее исключением, чем правилом в python

Comment: А что в вашем сравнении "не так как нужно"? С точки зрения питона, все как раз так, как и должно быть.

Comment: Вы можете уточнить суть вопроса? Вы хотите сравнивать адреса объектов в памяти или же значения и типы объектов? Какой результат сравнения вы ожидаете в случае сравнения `a` и `b` для: `a = 123456; b = 123456` - `False` (как в случае сравнения адресов или `True` если сравнивать значения и типы)?

Comment: Жалко, что вы не сочли нужным уточнить вопрос. В текущем виде он не вполне понятен. Почему "не так как нужно", или почему вы ожидали обратное - непонятно.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Если суть вопроса в сравнении значений и типов, то можно сделать так:

```
def strict_eq(obj1, obj2):
    if type(obj1) != type(obj2):
        return False
    return obj1 == obj2
```

---

```
In [4]: strict_eq(0, False)
Out[4]: False
```

---

PS можно пойти ещё дальше и для числовых типов сравнивать числа до определенной точности, чтобы избежать известных проблем с плавающей точкой:

```
In [5]: 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
Out[5]: False
```

---

функция строгого сравнения с определенной точностью:

```
from numbers import Number

def strict_eq(obj1, obj2, epsilon=1e-7):
    if type(obj1) != type(obj2):
        return False
    if isinstance(obj1, Number):
        return abs(obj1 - obj2) < epsilon
    return obj1 == obj2
```

---

```
In [10]: strict_eq(0.1 + 0.2, 0.3)
Out[10]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Для многих случаев возможно применить сравнение `id`ов:

```
id(0) == id(False)
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Это не совсем соответствует оператору `===` (JavaScript), но может быть полезным.

Comment: @MaxU, у меня нет такая, но `===` в Java значит что идет о тот же самый объект — потому адресы должны быть идентичными. Обратно, если адресы идентичны, то в контексте, когда нужно в Java применить оператор  `===`, т.е. когда знакомо, что идет об объекты того же самого типа, в Питоне возможно применить сравнение `id`ов.

Comment: @MaxU, ваш пример хороший, но практически никакой программист не применит эго в своей программе.

Comment: @MaxU, вы прав, у меня вероятно плохая память: 1. Я думал, что оператор `===` есть в Java, а его нет в Java, а в JavaScript. 2. Может быть, что я встретился с этим оператором в другом языке программирования с другой семантикой, но я забыл, в котором. - Спасибо за ваш комментарий, я сделаю правку в моем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Что именно вас смущает? В `Python` `True = 1`, а `False = 0`. Если вам надо сравнить именно слова `True` и `False`, тогда просто возьмите их в качестве строк например `0 == "False"`

Comment: сравните `type(0)` и `type(False)` - я думаю суть вопроса в этом